# open file through open dialog and keep the file as active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an active workbook with macro which has to open two other workbooks and make it as active workbooks.
but macro contained workbook remain as active workbook.
Please help.

```
With myFile
.Title = "Choose File"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then
Exit Sub
End If
SF = .SelectedItems(1)
SF = Application.GetOpenFilename(SF)
MsgBox SF

Workbooks.Open Filename:=(SF)



wb1 = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
MsgBox "SF" & SF
MsgBox "WB1" & wb1
```

The WB1 shows macro contained workbook's path. Not SF (Source file selected from openfile dialog box)

Further, is the below code correct?

```
For Rw = 4 To DF.Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For Rw1 = 3 To SF.Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If df.Sheet1.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = sf.Sheet1.Cells(Rw, 53).Value Then
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate the workbook you open with `object variable` which makes it easier to refer to each of the workbook in your code. So, instead of this line:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=(SF)
```

try with this solution:

```
Dim openWB as Workbook
Set openWB = Workbooks.Open(SF)
'and to activate it somewhere in your code you will need the following line:
openWB.Activate
```

**Remember, only ONE workbook can be active at the time.**

If you need to work with additional workbook you could add similar code once again but use new variable for this (like `Dim openWBNext as workbook` and so on...)

**The second part of your question...** Your code is not correct. But after you apply `object variables` as I presented above you could use this structures:

```
For Rw1 = 3 To openWB.Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If openWBNext.Sheet1.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = openWB.Sheet1.Cells(Rw, 53).Value Then
```

Comment: Dear Kazjaw, it works perfectly.  I have an another question. how to detect "00:30:00" from input box shift time like ("5:00:00).  Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: if you are happy with the answer you can always do [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). for the other question please ask new separate question, don't ask in comments?